# sparkR 1.6: How to predict probability when modeling with glm (binomial family)

Tags: sparkr

I have just installed sparkR 1.6.1 on CentOS and am not using hadoop. My code to model data with discrete 'TARGET' values is as follows:

```
# 'tr' is a R data frame with 104 numeric columns and one TARGET column
#    TARGET column is either 0 or 1
# Convert 'tr' to spark data frame

train <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, tr)

# test is an R dataframe without TARGET column
# Convert 'test' to spark Data frame
te<-createDataFrame(sqlContext,test)
# Using sparkR's glm model to model data
model <- glm(TARGET ~ . , data = train, family = "binomial")
# Make predictions
predictions <- predict(model, newData = te )
```

I am able to evaluate success or failure as follows (I hope I am correct):

```
modelPrediction <- select(predictions, "prediction")
head(modelPrediction)

  prediction
1          0
2          0
3          0
4          0
5          0
6          0
```

But when I want to evaluate probability, I get result as follows:

```
modelPrediction <- select(predictions, "probability")
head(modelPrediction)

                probability
1 <environment: 0x6188e1c0>
2 <environment: 0x61894b88>
3 <environment: 0x6189a620>
4 <environment: 0x618a00b8>
5 <environment: 0x618a5b50>
6 <environment: 0x618ac550>
```

Kindly help me in getting probability values of test events. Thanks.

Comment: please can you include the results of head(prediction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background: when your R code requests a result of some computation from Spark backend, Spark does the computation and serializes the result. This result is then deserialized on the R side and you get your R objects.

Now, the way it works on the Spark backend is -- if it figures that the type of the object to be returned is one of `Character`, `String`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double`  `Integer`, `Boolean`, `Date`, `TimeStamp` or their `Array` etc, then it serializes the object. But if it finds that the type does not match any of these, it simply assign the object an id, stores it in memory against that id, and sends this id to R client. (`JVMObjectTracker` in [RBackendHandler](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/r/RBackendHandler.scala) is responsible for keeping track of jvm object on spark backend.) This is then deserialized into [jobj](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/R/pkg/R/jobj.R) class on the R side. (You can look at `writeObject` method of [SerDe.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/r/SerDe.scala) to get the full picture of what is serialized upfront and what is not.)

Now, on the R side if you look at the objects in `probability` column of your `predictions` data frame, you will observe that their class is `jobj`. As mentioned, the objects of this class act as proxy to the actual Java objects held on the Spark cluster. In this particular case the backing java class is `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector`. This is a vector as it contains the probability for each class. And because this vector is not one of the serialized type supported by the SerDe class, spark backend just returns `jobj` proxy and stores these `DenseVector` object in memory so as to allow future operations on them.

With that background -- you should be able to get probability values on you R frontend by invoking methods on these `DenseVector` objects. As of now, I think this is the only way. Following is the code that works for iris data set --

```
irisDf <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, iris)
irisDf$target <- irisDf$Species == 'setosa'
model <- glm(target ~ . , data = irisDf, family = "binomial")
summary(model)
predictions <- predict(model, newData = irisDf)
modelPrediction <- select(predictions, "probability")
localPredictions <- SparkR:::as.data.frame(predictions)

getValFrmDenseVector <- function(x) {
    #Given it's binary classification there are just two elems in vector
    a <- SparkR:::callJMethod(x$probability, "apply", as.integer(0))
    b <- SparkR:::callJMethod(x$probability, "apply", as.integer(1))
    c(a, b)
}

t(apply(localPredictions, 1, FUN=getValFrmDenseVector))
```

with this I get the following probabilty output for two classes --

```
        [,1]         [,2]
1   3.036612e-15 1.000000e+00
2   5.919287e-12 1.000000e+00
3   7.831827e-14 1.000000e+00
4   7.712003e-13 1.000000e+00
5   4.427117e-16 1.000000e+00
6   3.816329e-16 1.000000e+00
[...]
```

Note: `SparkR:::` prefixed functions are not exported in the SparkR package namespace. So be keep in mind that you're coding against package private implementaion. (But I don't really see how this can be achieved otherwise, unless Spark provides a public API support for it.)

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate explanation. The solution proposed does work. And as you rightly mentioned,  callJMethod() does not have any help in sparkR shell. It is a part of sparkRBackend.R. Meanwhile, I was also able to get results using this code: 
modelPrediction <- select(predictions, "probability") ;
sink("abc.txt") ;
modelPrediction %>% showDF(numRows= 78000, truncate = FALSE) ; sink()

Comment: Cool, thanks. I will have a look at the showDF function too. (But that still not allows me to reference the probability values from within the code instead of printing them).