# Extracting vector Probabilities from SparkR ML RF without coercing a SparkDataFrame into an R data.frame

Tags: r, random-forest, sparkr

Check two relevant references 
[Extracting Class Probabilities from SparkR ML Classification Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41942974/extracting-class-probabilities-from-sparkr-ml-classification-functions/53812964#53812964) 
and
[sparkR 1.6: How to predict probability when modeling with glm (binomial family)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031987/sparkr-1-6-how-to-predict-probability-when-modeling-with-glm-binomial-family?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I'm just wondering whether there is any method to get these done without converting the SparkDataFrame back to an R data.frame via either as.data.frame or collect. Cuz it seems impossible when there is millions of data...

Comment: converting a 10^7 x 10 matrix to a data frame takes 0.638 seconds on my laptop (8G RAM)

Comment: It's really weird that it seems take forever to convert a 30,000,000 x 10 SparkR DataFrame to an R data frame although there's 20G executive memory. And it has no difficulty to convert a subsample of it, i.e. 500 x 10. Really desperated.